How do you pick up the systems selection color on macOS?
I'm trying to pick up the selection color from the system.  I see this throughout the system where the List row selection or icons that show up the system color
.accentColor(Color.primary)
.background(Color.secondary)
etc

The Colors API seams to only have .gray, .blue, .green etc and .secondary and .primary.  Hard coded names return their respective colors and secondary and primary seams to return blue.

Edit 1
This is what I settled on... It's a close match but not perfect.
List{}.listRowBackground(selected?.wrappedValue == listItem ? .accentColor.opacity( 0.85) : Color.clear)


Please don't update your question with your solution. Post an actual answer below instead.

@HangarRash I didn't want to lay claim to the answer which Sweeper did but Sweeper didn't print a specific line of code so I included it so the next person could just grab a line of code.

That's fine but you should still post it as an answer and not put it in the question. Give credit to Sweeper in that answer if you wish.

Color.accentColor is the "Accent Color" that the user selected in this page of System Settings (image from Apple Support):


The accent color is a broad theme color applied to views and controls. You can set it at the application level by specifying an accent color in your app’s asset catalog.


In macOS, SwiftUI applies customization of the accent color only if the user chooses Multicolor under General > Accent color in System Preferences.

If "Multicolor" is selected, Color.accentColor will be the color named "AccentColor" in the Asset Catalog.
The accentColor(_:) view modifier can change the color returned by Color.accentColor. That said, you should not use accentColor(_:) in the first place, as it has been deprecated since macOS 14.4. Most of its use cases can be replaced by .tint(_:), which doesn't change what Color.accentColor means.

I did try that so Maybe I didn't apply it to the correct place.  I'll fool around with the placement in my list control.  Not sure what .tint will do in this case should I try .background(.accentColor) or the List line background color?

kk got it to work .listRowBackground(selected?.wrappedValue == listItem ? .accentColor : Color.clear).  tint didn't work, background wasn't allowed but list row background was allowed.  TY !!!

@Keith Yes, you should use listRowBackground on list rows. The part about tint is rather irrelevant here since you are setting a list row's background (which is not clear from your question). I was commenting on the use of .accentColor(Color.primary) in the code you showed.

kk, I created a System based List {} and the colors are not quite right.  The systems colors are darker and mine are brighter.  Kind of garish I'll fool around with opacity.

This is what I settled on not perfect but closer.   .listRowBackground(selected?.wrappedValue == listItem ? .accentColor.opacity( 0.85) : Color.clear).  I'll work on more later there is some magic opacity I'm sure. :)
